# How to tune Windows 2008r2 and IIS to maximize single file download speeds?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, tcp

We recently put up an IIS site (on WinSvr 2008r2 running as a *Hyper-V* guest) that is used almost exclusively for downloading files over the internet.  The data exists as a large collection of .zip files ranging from 1MB - 35GB in size.  We want to allow a lot of downloads during a day (more than 500GB) but have implemented an outbound ASA throttle at 60mbps in order to preserve bandwidth for other uses.  The total link speed is 100mbps.

Here's the interesting part:  While we can serve up multiple downloads to hit the 60mbps cap, we cannot get any single download to exceed 2.5M bytes/sec (20 Mbits/s).  Is there any TCP or IIS tuning we can do to push up individual download speeds? Or something else to look at?

Comment: I'm guessing the client downloading has a >20Mbps download speed capacity for a single download?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Wrong topic - not needed. As in: 20mbit is very low - unless you did something utterly stupid (bad drivers etc.) that is not a tuning point. I would look for other weak points. like - how fast is the download link. This is NOT a "i need tuning" item. IT should work a lot faster without.

Comment: We've eliminated the download link by successfully downloading the same file from an alternate location where it DLs 1.5-2x faster. Definitely something slow about our setup for a single file.

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have some sort of throttling enabled on the IIS server? Something like: http://blogs.iis.net/rakkimk/archive/2008/04/04/iis7-configure-throttling-for-your-documents-any-mime-type-and-save-bandwidth-costs.aspx ... Also I'd double check that there isn't a misconfiguration on the ASA throttling individual streams at 20mbps

Comment: Thanks,@Zypher.  No bandwidth throttle in IIS at the site level.  The IIS bitrate throttle per mime type is a separate install and we've not added it.  We're checking the ASA config.

Comment: I'm interested to know if you tried to download data from the server by using any protocol other than HTTP, just to see that IIS is acting weird or is it a general server problem. can you use FTP? or use a different HTTP service other than IIS?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that IIS doesn't have maxbandwidth set to something wacky.

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/sites/site/limits

Tell your server's antivirus to ignore .zip files in your web directory.

You might want to experiment with:

- Disabling TCP Chimney Offload
- Disabling Receive Side Scaling
- Disabling Network Direct Memory Access

One or more of these might not be your friend.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951037

Comment: I tried each of these to no avail as yet.

Comment: :(  I was really hoping the AV thing would be your friend, as it's helped me in the past.

Comment: FYI - We're running the web server in a Hyper-V VM.  So chimney offload doesn't appear to be supported.

Comment: Oh, yes.  You're right, it's not, to my knowledge.  [edit]  Well.  If I recall correctly, I was told that in VMware, they'd have to turn it off for every VM in that vlan;  I'm not sure about Hyper-V.

Comment: Hello, I have same problem on server 2022 and IIS 10. Compared to nginx is like IIS is limited to 100-200 mbps speeds while nginx uses full network speed. Did you found solution? I'm surprised it doesn't work out of the box. I also asked question here https://serverfault.com/questions/1121437/iis-serving-files-strange-behavior?noredirect=1#comment1464496_1121437